# default backend - 404

Tags: ingress, rancher

I am currently running a small [K3S cluster](https://k3s.io/) in order to get familiar with K8S.

I am able to set up pods with ordinary LoadBalancers and get it to work without any problem.
However, when I try to get it to work with Ingresses (HAProxy in my case) - I only end up with "default backend -404".

This is the deployment of the pods, based on the default NGINX container:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: notesncrap
  labels:
    app: notesncrap
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: notesncrap
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: notesncrap
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: notesncrap
        image: jselea/notesncrap 
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

I have also created a Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: notesncrap
  labels:
    app: notesncrap
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
  selector:
    app: notesncrap
    tier: frontend
```

And now the Ingress:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: notesncrap
spec:
  rules:
  - host: k8scrap.selea.se
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: notesncrap
          servicePort: 80
```

I have the understanding that the name and label should be consistent over the .yaml files, and I personally can't see anything really wrong with what I have written.

Thankful for any pointers

EDIT:

As pointed out by the comments - the Ingress is behind a Apache Reverseproxy:

```
ProxyPass "/" "http://x.x.x.x:80"
ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://x.x.x.x:80"
ProxyRequests On
ProxyPreserveHost On
```

When I try curl directly against the ingress:

```
╭─root@sshgateway ~
╰─➤  curl -H "Host:k8scrap.selea.se" http://x.x.x.x                                                                                                                                   
default backend - 404#
```

Comment: are you sure that Host is `k8scrap.selea.se` ? 
I think that HTTP headers would be helpful in this case

Comment: @confiq you are correct; I already checked. Seems like default Apache Ubuntu server is being hit instead of the "app" - `< server: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu)`.

Comment: @Kyslik Apache is used as a reverseproxy in front of it. I have also tested with "curl -H "Host:k8scrap.selea.se" " against the ingress directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently - I forgot annotations and ingressclass:

I first added this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: IngressClass
metadata:
  annotations:
    ingressclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "true"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: haproxy
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: haproxy-ingress-controller
  name: haproxy
spec:
  controller: haproxy.org/ingress-controller
```

And in the ingress:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: notesncrap
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "haproxy"
  generation: 1
spec:
  rules:
  - host: k8scrap.selea.se
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: notesncrap
          servicePort: 80
```

Please observe the annotation.